# Upload an image directly from an Angular application to a S3 bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it necessary to rely on a backend server in order to upload an image from an Angular app to an Amazon S3 bucket?

There is for example [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3), which is a node.js middleware, and this implies at least 2 requests: The first one from the Angular app to the node.js server, and the second one to upload the file into the bucket.

Comment: Assuming you have the correct endpoints set up on the S3 Bucket, then yes, you can deposit an image to an S3 Bucket directly from Angular.

Comment: This from the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: Just for absolute clarity, you **DO NOT NEED** a **third party library** to do this. Look at the example link I provided. It is straight up HTML.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for the link, it clarifies that it is not necessary to use a third party library. It would be necessary though to secure the credentials on the client side, otherwise I read that there is presigned urls that grant the user a temporary access. These urls should still be generated on the server side if we don't want to keep the credentials on the client side

Comment: You have to get the initial web page from a server - that also provides the temp credentials - used once and removed either in code or by navigating to a different web page.

Answer (score 2):

As your first question: No, it is not necessary to use backend server in order to upload an image as you see here in [doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

There are a lot way's to do it. Some of them are as following.

> **Fine Uploader** is a pure-JavaScript browser-based file upload library
> with a long list of features that is unmatched by any other library.
> The power of Fine Uploader comes from its comprehensive set of
> options, API methods, and callbacks/events. The menu at the top of
> this page will give you access to more details regarding these three
> critical pieces of Fine Uploader. You can also read more about many of
> the features in the top navigation menu as well.

Same as well multer-s3 will help you to achieve this one too.

Link: [upload-images-from-angular-app-to-aws-s3-bucket-using-fineuploader](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/upload-images-from-angular-app-to-aws-s3-bucket-using-fineuploader-62601670b0fc)